# Configuring custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my project I'm creating custom **cells** by subclassing `UITableViewCell`. When `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is fired I do a pretty basic stuff like:

```
MyCustomCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[MyCustomCell identifier]];
```

I don't want to manually configure cell properties in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` so I thought I'd create a method inside `MyCustomCell` called `configureWithModel:` which is filling `MyCustomCell` with proper data. So far, so good! Now inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I have something like:

```
MyCustomCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[MyCustomCell identifier]];
[cell configureWithModel:model];
```

In `configureWithModel:` I assign some data (image also) to cell so as you'd guess it could be slow'n'heavy so I wonder **if this is a good solution to have a method like this in subclass of `MyCustomCell`? What is more, how it's related to `prepareForReuse`?**

Answer (score 0):

Doing this  `[cell configureWithModel:model];`  is the best approach because take for a case when you want to use `configureWithModel:` in more than 2 tableViews you can avoid code redundancy and cell level control would be there with cell itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use of `[cell configureWithModel:model];` will make your code look like more structured, but for image use the following delegate

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Example :

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(AlbumCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    AlbumBO *album = [self.arrAlbums objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    dispatch_async(imageQueue_, ^{
        UIImage *image = [self retrieveImageWithImageUrl:album.coverPhoto];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [cell.imgVwAlbum setImage:image];
        });
    });
}
```

Here

AlbumCell is my Custom table cell
AlbumBO is the object for containing image object

And

```
[self retrieveImageWithImageUrl:album.coverPhoto]
```

is the user defined method to download image.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a fairly decent usage of the singular responsibility principle. Where this might bite you is if your cells need to be binded with images that must be downloaded from a server. In this instance you don't want your cell responsible for triggering a download since the cell will then also be responsible for monitoring the progress of the download. Since these cells are reusable this becomes more problematic as the cell becomes reused.

So yes, in a simple case where you need to bind data to a cell it makes sense for the cell to be responsible for configuring its subviews with the relevant data.

Regarding `prepareForReuse` a casual glance at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/prepareForReuse) details

> Discussion If a UITableViewCell object is reusable—that is, it has a
>   reuse identifier—this method is invoked just before the object is
>   returned from the UITableView method
>   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:. For performance reasons, you
>   should only reset attributes of the cell that are not related to
>   content, for example, alpha, editing, and selection state. The table
>   view's delegate in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: should always
>   reset all content when reusing a cell. If the cell object does not
>   have an associated reuse identifier, this method is not called. If you
>   override this method, you must be sure to invoke the superclass
>   implementation.